# Orbeon Forms - link button

Tags: orbeon, linkbutton

I'm new to this Orbeon forms development. 
I want to know how to load or open a PDF on web browser when a link button is clicked.
I have already created a web service to load the PDF, I want to call that web service and open the PDF in a new tab of the web browser when the link button is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by "link button"? Are you referring to an `<a href="…">`? Should the link be in XForms you wrote by hand, or in a form you created with Form Builder? Can the service you're referring to be called with a simple GET? I.e. can you place the URL of the service in your browser, and get the PDF back?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant the link button control that you can directly drag and drop from Orbeon form builder tool box to the form being created using Form Builder. Yes when I place the URL of the service I can get the PDF back, which means the service has to be working.

Comment: Got it! Now that I better understand your question, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Link Button in Form Builder is more like a Button than a Link: it is intended to be used to run an HTTP or database service, for instance sending the value of some fields to that service, and using the result to populate other fields, or populate a dropdown. In your case, it looks like you just need a plain link. You can create such a link with the Explanatory Text control:

[image: Using the Explanatory Text control]

Comment: Good, I'm glad this worked for you, and thanks for confirming.